# Https not working on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have website https://darkcloud.app which is giving me error "This site can’t be reached" but it works fine without https and google is forcing to redirect with https when i am on chrome .Please help me.
[Route 53 setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZCaT.png)

[Security Group setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2F2fW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your domain name darkcloud.app is on the [HSTS preload list](https://hstspreload.org/?domain=darkcloud.app). This list is preloaded into browsers to tell them what sites must always be loaded over HTTPS. It means that Strict Transport Security is always enabled and it is mandatory to use https when accessing this web site.

**You will need to configure your web server for HTTPS.**

You can also request your domain be removed from the preload list, but it will require all users to update their browsers, which could take months or years, or possibly never. Being on the preload list means your domain effectively requires HTTPS forever.

Comment: Does That means i need to add ssl certificate to it ?

Comment: Yes, and you can use Let's Encrypt/certbot, or any other means of obtaining a certificate that you wish.